# Wait for user input before a send_message

Tags: python, telegram-bot

I'm having a problem with handling incoming messages. I have a main menu in my bot with one InlineKeyboardMarkup. When the button is pressed, the bot should wait for user input and then send a message. But in my case, it sends the message, then it waits for user input and then it sends again the message. And that's a big problem, because after the message it sends, it should go back to main menu.

I'm using pythonTelegramBotAPI (telebot)

That's the code:

```
  @bot.callback_query_handler(func = lambda call: True)
    def query_handler(call):
        bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id = call.id, text = '')
    
        cid = call.message.chat.id
        mid = call.message.message_id
        msg = call.message
    
     
        if call.data == 'request':
            bot.edit_message_text('Test - Answer to request', cid, mid, reply_markup = markup)
            request_handler(msg)
    
    ################# Keyboard sections #################
    
    @bot.message_handler()
    def request_handler(msg):
    
        if msg.content_type == 'text':
           bot.send_message(msg.chat.id, 'Request accepted')

# and here the code to go back, that I didn't do yet
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Correct answer

The decorator `@bot.messge_handler()` is used to tell to the function that it must be handle incoming messages. So, when there's a new message, the function will do the code inside it automatically. This means that **the function must not be called manually** as is not required. Calling the function will, in fact, run the code inside it, instead of initializing it and waiting for an input.

And here's a tip: if the user send a message, the function is automatically called. But what happens when the bot send a message? The function is also called, because it doesn't make difference about **who** sent the message. So, to avoid using the function also for bot messages, just put an if in like this:

```
if msg.from_user.is_bot == False:
   # Here put what the function should do
```

The if, as you can see, check if the message is coming from the bot.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this [conversational bot example](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/detailed_example/detailed_example.py) will help you to understand how to build dialog with user.